# rearranging the strings to make a new string

Tags: python-3.x

Given a string and an int n, print a string made of the first n characters of the string, followed by the first n-1 characters of the string, and so on. You may assume that n is between 0 and the length of  the string, inclusive (i.e. n >= 0 and n <= string length

example

```
chocolate, 4 -> Chocchochc
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Please see the advice on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask On a side note is this your homework? Literally this exact question?

Comment: Hi johnson, welcome to StackOverflow, please follow [mcve] as well the link above- how to ask, then feel free to edit your post, thanks in advance. 
Community will not the code it instead of you, if you improve the question, then somebody for sure will advise.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if I should actually post this but here you go. Even if it is homework it's so easy I doubt it will matter anyways but encourage you to do it yourself. If you can't solve such a problem you'll likely fail an exam anyways.

```
n = 4
string = "chocolate"
result = ""

while n > 0:
    result += string[:n]
    n -= 1

print(result)
```